# Sending AND receiving information through pipes?

Tags: c, process, pipe

I'm trying to better understand pipes between a parent and multiple child processes, so I made a simple program that spawns two child processes, gives them a value (`i`), has them change that value, and then prints it out.

However it's not working, as the program prints `i` as if it was unaltered, and prints the altered `i` inside the children. I'm obviously not sending the `i` variable through correctly, so how should I fix this?

```c
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int i=0;
    int pipefd[2];
    int pipefd1[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    pipe(pipefd1);
    pid_t cpid;
    cpid=fork();
    cpid=fork();
    if (cpid ==0)  //this is the child
    {
        close(pipefd[1]);   // close write end of first pipe
        close(pipefd1[0]);  // close read end of second pipe
        read(pipefd[0], &i, sizeof(i));
        i=i*2;
        printf("child process i= %d\n",i);  //this prints i as 20 twice
        write(pipefd1[1],&i, sizeof(i));
        close(pipefd[0]); // close the read-end of the pipe
        close(pipefd1[1]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } 
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);   // close read end of first pipe
        close(pipefd1[1]);  // close write end of second pipe
        i=10;
        write(pipefd[1],&i,sizeof(i));  
        read (pipefd1[1], &i, sizeof (i));
        printf("%d\n",i); //this prints i as 10 twice
        close(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd1[0]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're not creating two child processes.  You're creating three.

```
cpid=fork();
cpid=fork();
```

The first `fork` results in a child process being created.  At that point, both the child and the parent execute the next statement, which is also a `fork`.  So the parent creates a new child and the first child also creates a child.  That's why everything is printing twice.

You need to check the return value of `fork` immediately before doing anything else.

If you were to remove one of the `fork` calls, you'd still end up with the wrong value for `i` in the parent.  That's because it's reading from the wrong end of the pipe.

The child is writing to `pipefd1[1]`, but the parent is then trying to read from `pipefd1[1]` as well.  It should be reading from `pipefd1[0]`.

EDIT:

Removed erroneous sample code which assumed pipes are bidirectional, which they are not.

Comment: Ok, I had read that pipes were unidirectional, from http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe , which was recommended by a professor. So I can just create 1 pipe and then alternatively open and close the ends when I want to read and write from it both ways?

Comment: @tokola Actually, you're correct.  Pipes are unidirectional.  I removed the erroneous code from my answer.